# Why does "\1" inside a triple-quoted string evaluate to a unicode 0x1 code point

Tags: groovy, heredoc, unicode-escapes

I wanted a String containing a text `\1`.

What I did was (the real string was longer but it's not important):

```
'''
 \1
'''
```

Which resulted in a String containing a unicode `0x1` codepoint.

I think what I should've done is just escape the backslash like this:

```
'''
 \\1
'''
```

What I don't understand is why Groovy didn't report an error here. I thought unicode escapes are [supposed to look like `\u1`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_unicode_escape_sequence)?

Instead of a syntax error I got a runtime exception when I tried to put this String into an XML element:

```
An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x1) was found in the element content of the document.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\` (backward slash) symbol is an [escape symbol](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_escaping_special_characters). If you mean to use it literally, you must escape it itself: `\\`.

When you escape any character, the character is interpreted to have special meaning. In the case of the `\1` sequence, it just happens that this can be interpreted as the `0x01` codepoint.

This is the same in Java Strings.

If you want to not have to escape characters in Groovy, use [slashy strings](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_slashy_string):

```
def x = /\1/
assert x == "\\1"
```

which also works as multiline:

```
def x = /
\1
/
```

Comment: Now that you pointed it out I realized it's the [octal escape sequence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6) -- I could swear they have to start with `\0` but apparently they don't

Comment: Re. slashy string -- nice suggestion, but I actually *don't* want interpolation to work there