# Loop through files in folder, read and group files

Tags: python

I am trying to read a csv file, resample it and save it with a different name

So far I got this:

```html
import fnmatch
import os

for file in os.listdir('C:\Users\AZERTY\Desktop\1.1 pandas.zip\2021\'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.csv'):
        mydata = pd.read_csv(file)
        mydata.columns = ["Date-Time", "Frequency"]
        mydata['Date-Time'] = pd.to_datetime(mydata['Date-Time'])
        mydata = mydata.set_index('Date-Time')
        mydata.index = pd.to_datetime(mydata.index)
        df = mydata.resample('1S').mean()
        df = df.fillna('nearest')
        df.to_csv(file +'fixed' +'.csv')
```

But I get an error due to syntax being wrong, any ideas?

Comment: what is the full error? Where is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One error I could see is that you use backslashes ("\") in your path. The backslash serves as escape character in python strings which means that the backslash together with the following symbol could have a special meaning. You should double all backslashes in paths like so:

```
for file in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\AZERTY\\Desktop\\1.1 pandas.zip\\2021\\'):
```

Or alternatively  you can use pythons "raw" string by putting an "r" in front of it like this:

```
for file in os.listdir(r'C:\Users\AZERTY\Desktop\1.1 pandas.zip\2021\'):
```

Comment: thank you, I changed the code to the r'path and now its working

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape some parts of your string with a backslash:

```
'C: \Users\AZERTY\Desktop\\1.1 pandas.zip\\2021\\'
```

Assuming you are getting a *string literal is undetermined error*

> [Why does "\1" inside a triple-quoted string evaluate to a unicode 0x1 code point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37215351/why-does-1-inside-a-triple-quoted-string-evaluate-to-a-unicode-0x1-code-point)